# HTML/CSS - What's the best way to have a partially expanded element?

Tags: html, css

Lets say I have a 980px centered content area but there's a background element that expands all the way from the left of the screen to 80% of the content area. How do you accomplish this without JavaScript intervention or using a background image on the body?

EDIT:

Here's a visual concept for guidance: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgKal.jpg. The yellow header expands to the left of the window, outside of the content box area.

Comment: what is the "background element"? a div? an image?

Comment: @GionaF It would be a div, that has text ontop of it.

Comment: mmh..can you provide your code? i'm not sure i understand what you're looking for

Comment: @GionaF No code yet. Check out http://i.imgur.com/36tCm.jpg to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the overhang effect with a div element before the 980px container and give positioning to match where the header element is

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/eR3L3/1/) or [fullscreen example](http://jsfiddle.net/eR3L3/1/show)

in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgKal.jpg) you've got an orange overhang on the left and black on the right so here's the HTML structure (alternatively you could do the overhang with a single div and css gradients to create an orange color up to 50% then black the other 50%)

```
<div class="container-outer">
    <div class="header-overhang header-left"></div>
    <div class="header-overhang header-right"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            sidebar area
        </div>
        <div class="header">
            PAGE HEADER
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            content text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.container-outer {background-color:#BDC7D2;border-top:60px solid #050912;}
.header-overhang {height:72px;width:50%;position:absolute;top:60px;}
.header-left {left:0;background-color:#FDC103;}
.header-right {right:0;background-color:#050912;}
.container {width:980px;margin:0 auto;position:relative;}

.sidebar {float:right;width:20%;height:220px;line-height:220px;text-align:center;border-top:5px solid #d7e0e9;border-bottom:3px solid #d7e0e9;background-color:#fff;}
.header {height:72px;line-height:72px;padding-left:40px;width:80%;background-color:#FDC103;}
.content {padding:50px 40px 120px 120px;background:#050912;color:#fff;}
```

Comment: Bam, thanks! This is exactly the kind of logic I was hoping to get. Makes sense and is a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 1):

You Handle this issue by css

```
#inner{
   background:#fff;
   width:80%;
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   top:0;
}
```

And you should set for its parents this style

```
#parent{
   position:relative;
}
```

For example :

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem w/ this approach is 80% isn't always going to be dead on. It needs to stick all the way to 80% of the centered-div content area.. Which is where it gets tricky.

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this with a bit of visual trickery--namely, by using two yellow divs to create the visual effect of the `#pageheader` element.

Here's a [JSFiddle illustrating the effect](http://jsfiddle.net/sAmYP/).

Here's some sample HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="yellowBar">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="pageHeader">
  <!--the rest of your HTML...-->
```

Then, your CSS:

```
#yellowBar {
  height: (set appropriate height here);
  background: yellow (set appropriate hex code here); 
  position: absolute;
  top: (set appropriate top value so the #yellowBar nudges up against the #pageHeader visually);
  width: 50%;
  left: 0px;
}

#pageHeader {
  height: (same height as #yellowBar); 
  background: (same color as yellowBar); 
  width: 80%; 
  /*any other CSS rules*/ 
}
```